# tv tuner will ubuntu install in place of windows media centre

Tags: system-installation

Hi I have a medion 1000gb with windows built in if i switch to Ubuntu will it automatically install tv tuner and if so does it have similar to windows media centre please be gentle am thick with computers 
cheers doug

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to know whether some special hardware will be usable in Ubuntu. You could search for the product name and then search the internet for any reviews but there is an easier way.

If you burn a Ubuntu installation CD, you can use it not only to install Ubuntu, but also for trying it out without touching your installed system. Then you can just install some TV Software from the Ubuntu Software Center and see if it works.

If you can't use the TV Card immediately, that doesn't say that it's completely unusable with Ubuntu, but it would take some time to get it working.